# Typescript get class properties list with types

Tags: typescript

I have a class with properties (like name, date,...)

```
class Product {
   name: string
   date: Date
}
```

What I expect is to get a list of properties with type :

```
[{field: "name", type: "string"}, {field: "date", type: "Date"}]
```

**Edit :**

I want to do that because I'm creating a scaffold tool to create with CLI a new object.

Eg.

`scaffold new Object --fields=[{name: "foo", type: "number"}]`

Comment: Is the result a type or a value? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Do you want a function that does this? If so, do you want to pass a class to the function? This might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: SHould list be the value of literal type?

Comment: Typescript types are erased at runtime so you can't do this.

Comment: @LindaPaiste OP doesn't need the information at runtime. They can parse the code and extract the info. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-parser and examples at https://github.com/buehler/node-typescript-parser/blob/master/test/TypescriptParser.spec.ts#L488